# Unsupervised gen_server doesn't call terminate when it receives exit signal

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server

`gen_server` documentation on `Module:terminate` callback says:

> Even if the gen_server process is not part of a supervision tree, this
>   function is called if it receives an 'EXIT' message from its parent.
>   Reason is the same as in the 'EXIT' message.

Here is my `handle_info` and `terminate` function:

```
handle_info(UnknownMessage, State) ->
    io:format("Got unknown message: ~p~n", [UnknownMessage]),
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(Reason, State) ->
    io:format("Terminating with reason: ~p~n", [Reason]).
```

I start this server using `gen_server:start`. I assume when I call `erlang:exit(Pid, fuckoff)`, it should call `terminate` callback function. But it shows:

```
Got unknown message: {'EXIT',<0.33.0>,fuckoff}
```

Which means it is calling `handle_info`. But when I call `gen_server:stop`, everything works as mentioned in documentation. I'm calling my `gen_server` from shell. Would you please clarify this?

**[UPDATE]**

[Here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/gen_server.erl#L383) is source code of `decode_msg` function inside `gen_server`. If it receives any 'EXIT' message it should call `terminate` function:

```
decode_msg(Msg, Parent, Name, State, Mod, Time, Debug, Hib) ->
    case Msg of
    {system, From, Req} ->
        sys:handle_system_msg(Req, From, Parent, ?MODULE, Debug,
                  [Name, State, Mod, Time], Hib);
    {'EXIT', Parent, Reason} ->
        terminate(Reason, Name, Msg, Mod, State, Debug);
    _Msg when Debug =:= [] ->
        handle_msg(Msg, Parent, Name, State, Mod);
    _Msg ->
        Debug1 = sys:handle_debug(Debug, fun print_event/3,
                      Name, {in, Msg}),
        handle_msg(Msg, Parent, Name, State, Mod, Debug1)
end.
```

In my case it doesn't call `terminate` function.

**[UPDATE]**

When I start `gen_server` using `gen_server:start_link()`, sending an exit signal using `erlang:exit(Pid, Reason)` will result in calling `terminate` call back function which is an expected behaviour. It seems there is a difference in interpreting an exit signal whether a process is linked to its parent or not.

Comment: Did you set the `trap_exit` flag of process to `true` somewhere in the code?

Comment: Yes. Inside `init` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**

If you call the `exit/2` function from inside the `gen_server` actor, it behaves as expected based on the documentation and the `terminate/2` callback will be called.

**Long answer:**

When you send the exit message from the shell, the `Parent` value of exit tuple is set to the shell process id, on the other hand when you start the `gen_server` process form shell its `Parent` value is set to its own process id, not the shell process id, therefore when it gets the exit message it doesn't match the second clause of the receive block in `decode_msg/8` function so the `terminate/6` function is not called and finally the next clause is matched which is calling `handle_msg/5` function.

**Recommendation:**

For getting the `terminate/3` callback called even by sending an exit message to the `gen_server` process, you can trap the exit message in `handle_info/2` and then return with stop tuple as follows:

```
init([]) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    {ok, #state{}}.

handle_info({'EXIT', _From, Reason}, State) ->
    io:format("Got exit message: ~p~n", []),
    {stop, Reason, State}.

terminate(Reason, State) ->
    io:format("Terminating with reason: ~p~n", [Reason]),
    %% do cleanup ...
    ok.
```

Comment: I got it. I can see that in `observer`. Why the parent is set to its own process id when I start a process in shell? Any special reason?

Comment: @MajidAzimi: Based on the code, the `gen:get_parent/0` which is responsible for finding the parent of `gen_server` looks for the first item of `$ancestors` key in the process dictionary. As the `gen_server` process is an OTP process which is started with `proc_lib`, it should have the calling actor process ID in the `$ancestors` dictionary, which is the shell process ID in this case and set it as parent, but it doesn't work as expected. I need more time to find whether it's a bug or something else.

Comment: As far as I can check, when I start an OTP process using `gen_*:start` the parent pid is set to newly created process itself. When starting with `gen_*:start_link` it is set to the first element of `$ancestors`. It doesn't matter if the actual parent is shell or other gen_*. In both case `$ancestors` contains all parents up to the root. `gen_*:start_link` is using first element of `$ancestors` to get the parent(which is the expected behaviour) but for some reason `gen_*:start` uses its own pid as parent.

Answer (score 0):

When you start your `gen_server`, its a simple process, so, [`erlang:exit/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#exit-1) or [`erlang:exit/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#exit-2) work as expected.

> - If Pid is not trapping exits, Pid itself exits with exit reason Reason.
> - If Pid is trapping exits, the exit signal is transformed into a message {'EXIT', From, Reason} and delivered to the message queue of Pid.

So, currently your code trap `'EXIT'` signal because this one is send like any other message into the mailbox and match `handle_info/2` wildcard pattern.

If you want more information about that, you can read [`gen_server`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/gen_server.erl#L199) source code and see how it works. You can also find [your problem](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/gen_server.erl#L54) described in this code.

Comment: Let me ask the question this way: `gen_server:stop` also sends exit signal. It will be converted to 'EXIT' message. How `gen_server` differentiate this message from my 'EXIT' message (which comes from `exit`)

Comment: `gen_server:handle_info/2` is currently used to trap every signal (even special one). So, if you want to differentiate `'EXIT'` signal from other signal, your definition of `handle_info` need to be different (modifying pattern matching, adding guards...). To be clear, `'EXIT'` signal is more like a convention than a standard in Erlang, because its only a simple message.